# How do I get the list of jar files to be included in classpath for Okta java-api calls?

Tags: java, maven, jar, okta, okta-api

I have already built the okta-sdk-0.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar using maven, and I am able to compile my test api code without issues. 
https://github.com/okta/oktasdk-java

However, at **runtime**, the API calls need some more jar files, for example the one that includes packages like: org.apache.http.Header, etc..

Of course I can go on guessing which dependent JAR files are missing in my classpath by looking at the runtime errors, but I am looking for any known list of runtime dependencies.

Thanks,

Jatin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are required dependencies. One or two of them might be extra, but the shown list covers all the required ones.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend adding the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) to your build to create an uber jar. That is a jar which includes all required dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can create uber jar with all the dependencies in the final jar as follows .

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>uber-${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

or you can copy all the dependencies to lib folder to used while starting the server.

```
<build> 
  <plugins> 
    <plugin> 
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId> 
    <executions> 
      <execution> 
        <phase>install</phase> 
          <goals> 
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal> 
          </goals> 
          <configuration> 
             <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory> 
          </configuration> 
        </execution> 
      </executions> 
    </plugin> 
  </plugins> 
</build>
```